# Scala: lambda is passed to a function, gets wrapped into Runnable and does not get executed afterwards - what is going on?

Tags: scala, lambda, runnable, parametric-polymorphism

Consider the following code (you can run it directly on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/uV2fGM)):

```
object Main extends App {
  def foo[T](code: => T) : Runnable = new Runnable { def run = code }
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x: Runnable = foo(() => {
      System.out.println("b")
    })
    val y: Runnable = foo({
      System.out.println("d")
    })
    System.out.println("a")
    x.run()
    System.out.println("c")
    y.run()
    System.out.println("e")
  }
}
```

It prints `a c d e`, which means that the first lambda is successfully passed to `foo`, but is not executed when I call `x.run()`. The second one, however, is executed successfully.

If I remove that wrapping into `Runnable` and run these lambdas directly, both of them work. I met this behavior when I was working with a Scala binding for Java library.

What is going on here? What happened to `x`, why does it have some correct value but do nothing?

Comment: If you build with `-Ywarn-value-discard` you will be warned about these kind of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foo's parameter `code` is a lazy `T` (aka `=> T`).

In `foo(System.out.println("d"))`, `code` is a lazy `Unit` because that's what `println` returns. So the runnable will turn that lazy `Unit` into an actual `Unit`.

Whereas in `foo(() => System.out.println("d")})`, `code` is a lazy `() => Unit`. Which means the runnable is turning a lazy `() => Unit` into an actual `() => Unit` function - but the function itself is never run.

Here's a simpler example:

```
scala> def foo[T](code: => T) = code
foo: [T](code: => T)T

//`code` is evaluated to a `Unit`
scala> val x = foo(println("a"))
a
x: Unit = ()

//`code` is evaluated to a `() => Unit` function, but the function is never run
scala> val y = foo(() => println("a"))
y: () => Unit = <function0>
```